# How to pronounce 'll after ll?

Tags: pronunciation

> “Reckon old **Dill’ll** be coming home tomorrow.” (Harper Lee, To Kill
>   A Mockingbird)

How do you pronounce ‘ll after ll?
(Would you let me get the IPA (phonetic alphabet))

Comment: I'm surprised this has a close vote already. This particular instance is from a classic in American literature, but the answer could be useful to anyone else who wants to use this same construction in the future ("There goes Jack; watch, Jill'll come tumbling down at any moment.")

Comment: Me too! It is a real constructive question. I learned a new thing by this.

Comment: @J.R. I guess that the users who voted to close think this only happens in few cases.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It wouldn't necessarily be restricted to names of people, either. _I heard a financial analyst on the radio today; he said, "I think Apple'll be up next quarter, but Dell'll be down."_ (Mind you, I wouldn't write it that way, unless the analyst had enunciated it that way, but it's still an interesting question, I think.)

Comment: @J.R. I find it interesting too, also because I think few English learners would know how to pronounce that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it's a contraction of *Dill will* it's "Dill-ull"  (*ull* as in *full*) and run together with no pause.

> /'dɪlʊl/

Comment: This is the “correct” way to say it. But in fact, in my part of the country (which is Harper Lee’s), the /l/ in “Dill” would be reduced to a ʊ-glide unless followed by a syllable beginning with a vowel; so we’d actually say /'dɪʷl/.

Comment: @StoneyB- Agreed.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think for the quoted example I'd be more inclined to pronounce it as something closer to "Dill luh", though with other words I might alter the consonant of the main word and keep the ending of "will".

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary says [*'ll*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/'ll) is pronounced /əl/, [əl], [l̩], [ɫ̩], [ʊ], [ɯ], i.e. phonemically it's /əl/ and phonetically it's one of [əl], [l̩], [ɫ̩], [ʊ], [ɯ] (possibly an incomplete list) depending on your variety of English.

- [əl] - [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) with "l"
- [l̩] - [syllabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant) "l"
- [ɫ̩] - syllabic ["dark l"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_lateral_approximants#Velarized_alveolar_lateral_approximant)
- [ʊ] - [near-close back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_back_rounded_vowel)
- [ɯ] - [close back unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_back_unrounded_vowel)

To me, [ɫ̩] is a cross between [l] and [w], so a "w" coloured "l". [w] is a semivowel and is related to [u], which [ʊ] and [ɯ] are similar to. So all the sounds are similar, the main difference being vowel vs. schwa with consonant vs. syllabic consonant.

So *Dill'll* is pronounced /'dɪləl/, with the exact pronunciation depending on your variety of English.